# how to get the value of string based on my separator

Tags: apex, string, substring

I need to get this string before my separator, in this case a pipe character (`'|'`).

So if I have this data:

```
Malcolm Bell Landgraab | EMP-00012 | Consultant
Juliawati Sandra | EMP-00003 | Consultant
```

I want this output:

```
['Malcolm Bell Landgraab', 'EMP-00012', 'Consultant']
['Juliawati Sandra', 'EMP-00003', 'Consultant']
```

How can I accomplish this task?

[image]

Comment: Use `someString.split('\\|')`. I cleaned up your question for you, they're a lot more accessible as text.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I think that will still provide an output with white spaces for some characters

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Your answer was close, you just forgot about the regular expression part of String.split. You could still fix your answer...

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks ! Yes I realized it .Looks like eric has it covered before me

Comment: @Vikolai - Is that one string with two rows or two separate strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I aM splitting it with respect to newline character and | character.
This will work for you.

```
String inputString='Malcolm Bell Landgraab | EMP-00012 | Consultant\nJuliawati Sandra | EMP-00003 | Consultant';
String []rowsData=inputString.split('\n');

for(String individualROw : rowsData){
    String[] rowArray = individualROw.split('\\|');
        System.debug('[\''+rowArray[0].trim()+'\',\''+rowArray[1].trim()+'\',\''+rowArray[2].trim()+'\']\n' );
        }
```

If you only want record of Employee only Print rowArray[1] and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

This will split it and remove whitespace:

```
String initialString = 'Malcolm Bell Landgraab | EMP-00012 | Consultant';
String[] results = initialString.trim().split('\\s*\\|\\s*');
system.debug(results);
```

Of course you will want to add in all the usual checks for null, errors, etc.

For a single string this will get you the EMP part as requested in your comments:

**Note** I am not the best at regex so best I can do at this point:

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('(?<=EMP)([^\\s\\|]*)(?=[$\\s\\|])');
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(initialString);
Boolean result = MyMatcher.find();
String emp;
if(result){
    emp = 'EMP' + MyMatcher.group(0);
}
system.debug(emp);
```

Comment: thanks, but how if i just want to get the EMP-00012 only? @eric

Comment: @Vikolai - That is a different question. It would just be a matter of using the right regex expression and has nothing to do with your original question

Comment: so i need to post one more question? with my point is to ask how to get string based on pipe separator '|' ? @eric
what i want achieve is comparing EMP-00012 with my other field, so i just need to get EMP-00012

Comment: @Vikolai - See updated answer. Note only for a single string. If multiple string you will need to split them and iterate over the individual ones

Comment: @Vikolai - Curious, where in you question did you actually state that all you wanted was the "EMP-xxx' part cause I do not see it in any form? In the future if you want a question answered you actually need to put it in the question that you post. It is very difficult to read into questions when they are posted as text

Comment: ok sorry sir @eric but your code not working hehe thanks

Comment: @Vikolai - then you are doing something wrong as it was tested Before it was posted. Answer you accepted was using the same code I posted so Hehe

Comment: hmm oke, but it was got error message at your code hehe :
Line: 1, Column: 36
Invalid string literal '(?<=EMP)([^\\s\\|]*)(?=[$\\s\|])'. Illegal character sequence '\|' in string literal.
@Eric

Comment: @Vikolai - Apologies, typo on my part it was missing a \. You are going to have to learn how to troubleshoot error messages like that if you want to improve your apex skills. I have added the missing \ in the answer so feel free to give it another try. Just a note, comments like hehe (seems like snickering or laughing) do not encourage people to want to spend their valuable time assisting those that make those comments.